# ajax call and page redirection

Tags: ajax, web-applications

I am making a ajax call in a page. Before getting the ajax response,
if user navigate to other page, 
will the ajax call will be completed?

1. page loads
2. user doing some action, which making ajax call at
   background and updating in server.
3. before ajax call gets response,user navigated to some other page.
4. Will that ajax call will be completed?

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

No.  Whatever action the ajax call initiates on the server will *probably* finish (ie, the php script), but the browser will not receive the response.